# search keywords in a larger output in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have output like this.

"vlan_output['stdout_lines'][0]": [

```
 "VLAN Name                             Status    Ports", 
    "---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------", 
    "1    default                          active    Po10, Po11, Eth1/44, Eth1/45", 
    "                                                Eth1/46, Eth1/47, Eth1/48", 
    "                                                Eth2/1, Eth2/2, Eth2/3", 
    "2    VLAN0002                         active    Po11, Po12, Po121, Eth1/1", 
    "                                                Eth1/2, Eth1/3, Eth1/4, Eth1/47", 
    "                                                Eth1/48", 
    "3    VLAN0003                         active    Po11, Po12, Po121, Eth1/1", 
    "                                                Eth1/2, Eth1/3, Eth1/4, Eth1/47", 
    "                                                Eth1/48", 
    "4    VLAN0004                         active    Po11, Po12, Po121, Eth1/1",
```

VLAN here shows 1,2,3,4
Usually we get range of vlans to delete. After deleting, I need to make sure they are not in the output.  ofcourse actual output will have lot of vlans. 
usually we get range like this 3000-3005,3200,3400-3402

After we delete, how do I search in this output? In the above output 3000,3001,3002,3003,3004,3005,3200,3400,3401,3402(3000-3005=3001,3002,3003,3004,3005)  should not be in the output.

I am new to Ansible. Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: in the above case you should focus on the data structure you are getting from the command. Once you have analyzed the data structure you need to use one of the modules to search

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes its a list. I tried using like this   - set_fact: run_pc="{{vlan_output['stdout_lines'][0]" |select('search',match_str) | list | join(' ')}}", but his returns all that matches string match_str. matchstr='VLAN0003'. Problem here is it matches 'VLAN00033' , 'VLAN00034' also. How do I do exact match

Answer (score 0):

The below is not a complete answer but a start to the problem you have posted.

playbook -->

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: play
      set_fact:
        file_lines: "{{ lookup('file', 'table').split('\n') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      when: item | search("VLAN")
      with_items: "{{ file_lines | list}}"
```

output -->

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using tests as filters is deprecated. Instead of using `result|search` use `result is search`. This feature will
be removed in version 2.9. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
ok: [localhost] => (item="VLAN Name                             Status    Ports", ) => {
    "msg": "\"VLAN Name                             Status    Ports\", "
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=    "---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------", )
skipping: [localhost] => (item=    "1    default                          active    Po10, Po11, Eth1/44, Eth1/45", )
skipping: [localhost] => (item=    "                                                Eth1/46, Eth1/47, Eth1/48", )
skipping: [localhost] => (item=    "                                                Eth2/1, Eth2/2, Eth2/3", )
ok: [localhost] => (item=    "2    VLAN0002                         active    Po11, Po12, Po121, Eth1/1", ) => {
    "msg": "    \"2    VLAN0002                         active    Po11, Po12, Po121, Eth1/1\", "
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=    "                                                Eth1/2, Eth1/3, Eth1/4, Eth1/47", )
skipping: [localhost] => (item=    "                                                Eth1/48", )
ok: [localhost] => (item=    "3    VLAN0003                         active    Po11, Po12, Po121, Eth1/1", ) => {
    "msg": "    \"3    VLAN0003                         active    Po11, Po12, Po121, Eth1/1\", "
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=    "                                                Eth1/2, Eth1/3, Eth1/4, Eth1/47", )
skipping: [localhost] => (item=    "                                                Eth1/48", )
ok: [localhost] => (item=    "4    VLAN0004                         active    Po11, Po12, Po121, Eth1/1",) => {
    "msg": "    \"4    VLAN0004                         active    Po11, Po12, Po121, Eth1/1\","
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**I have used lookup to get the required info but you can use the output of the register variables
**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using simple regex

- set_fact: vlan_regex="VLAN0003\s"
- set_fact: run_vlan="{{ vlan_output['stdout_lines'] [0] | select('search',vlan_regex) | list}}"
- debug: var=run_vlan

Simple regex that has the keyword followed by space